# Icon List Menu not aligning properly in IE 7

Tags: css

I have this alignment issue in css for IE7. I am trying to create this icon with text menu and it works fine in firefox and IE 8, but in IE7, the float is not happening. Why i chose this type of html code, is to have a hover effect when hovering the list, use image sprite instead of images. Can somebody please correct me where i am going wrong. The html and css code is as follows..

CSS Code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.designDetailLinks {
display:block; float:right;  position:relative;
}
.designDetailLinks li {
display:block; float:left; margin:0 0 0 0; font-size:92%; width:auto; 
}
.designDetailLinks .editCTO {
display:block;  padding:26px 0 0 0;color:#575656; width:40px; margin:0 auto; text-align:center; 
background:url(../images/icons.gif) no-repeat 0 -2229px;
}
.designDetailLinks .editCTO:hover {
display:block;  color:#1d8e3f; 
background:url(../images/icons.gif) no-repeat 0 -2270px;
}
.designDetailLinks .BOM {
display:block;  padding:26px 0 0 0; color:#575656; width:40px; margin:0 auto;  text-align:center; 
background:url(../images/icons.gif) no-repeat 0 -2313px;
}
.designDetailLinks .BOM:hover {
display:block;   color:#1d8e3f;
background:url(../images/icons.gif) no-repeat 0 -2313px;
}
.designDetailLinks strong {
display:block; text-align:center; clear:left;
}
</style>
```

HTML Code :

```
<div class="designDetailLinks">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="BOM"></a><strong>Edit BOM</strong></li>
<li><a href="#" class="editCTO"></a><strong>Edit CTO </strong></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you had a live example of your code, it would be easier for us to debug it.

Comment: If you use the same code in a plain HTML file, you can still see the problem i am talking about...

Comment: a live example would certainly help, but my best guess would be your combination of position tricks, the floats, auto margin, and centered text. the issue for me is I am not sure what your goal is, how you want it to look. btw, for hovering over the link, if you want it to effect the text try .BOM:hover + string (otherwise I can't understand why you would change the color on hover, there is no content in the link).

Answer (score 0):

Which float are you talking about, and why are you floating right and left?

As per the previous comments, I'd be inclined to simplify the HTML and CSS -- it's hard to work out what's going on, given all the different rules, some of which appear to be redundant.

For the HTML, you could use something like this (in fact, the classes here should probably be IDs, since they're unique identifiers):

```
<ul class="designDetailLinks">
  <li><a href="#" class="BOM">Edit BOM</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="editCTO">Edit CTO</a></li>
</ul>
```

...or even just put anchor elements inside a div (though this might offend list purists).

Then the CSS could look something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.designDetailLinks li a {
background:url(../images/icons.gif) no-repeat; 
display:block; 
font-size:90%; /* sensible to stick with multiples of 5 */
font-weight: bold; 
padding: 26px 0 0 0; 
text-align: center; 
width: 40px; 
}
.designDetailLinks .editCTO {
background-position: 0 -2229px;
}
.designDetailLinks .editCTO:hover {
background-position: 0 -2270px;
}
.designDetailLinks .BOM {
background-position: 0 -2313px;
}
.designDetailLinks .BOM:hover {
background-position: 0 -2313px; /* BTW: is this pixel value wrong? */
}
</style>
```